# AutoHotkey: Unable to Send Plus Sign in String

Tags: regex, autohotkey

Gave a try in SO as well as lot of communities but No Luck!

I Have a file path `\\ParentFolder\ChildFolder1\ChildFolder2\113700+112688+18923466+100.56.pdf` which needs to be sent in a Dialog Box. As the file contains a `+` sign it is getting replaced by `!` when i send the string through `Send` or `SendRaw`. Is there any other ways that i can send the path along with the `+` sign.

Comment: In addition to Jim U's answer `SendRaw` also should work. It's supposed to ignore special characters and just send the input as is.

Comment: @Oleg I have tried using 'SendRaw' and didn't work for me.

Comment: That's strange, can you post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with `SendRaw`? Not really important if your problem is already solved but I'm curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` is a special character that sends the following character with <kbd>shift</kbd>. You can avoid this by using curly braces `{+}`

```
send \\ParentFolder\ChildFolder1\ChildFolder2\113700{+}112688{+}18923466{+}100.56.pdf
```

You were getting exclamation points because the pluses all preceed ones and <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> is <kbd>!</kbd>.

REF:

- Autohotkey Documentation for [Send](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the Explanation Jim! Lemme try and get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

Just use {Raw} before your string, here test script:

```
::test::
Send {Raw}\\ParentFolder\ChildFolder1\ChildFolder2\113700+112688+18923466+100.56.pdf
```

Launch it, write test press space and see, it writes everything you wanted.